# Trying to print a pdf via chromium (and google chrome) headless cli

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf, chromium, pdftk

I have a problem with the chromium print to pdf.
I have a fillable PDF Form that I fill with PHP. After that I have a filled PDF-Form.
But the problem is, that the filled form is displayed wonderful in Chrome, but on in Firefox and Safari some checkboxes and fields are not filled.
Now I want to convert the Fillable (and filled) PDF to a "printed" PDF (as if you click print in your browser and print as PDF). Then there are no fields and nothing to be false.
But I am very disappointed that i have not found any library that can do that without errors.
So I tried the headless chromium:

```
chromium --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --print-to-pdf=file1.pdf http://<url>/form.pdf
```

But that does only throws `[0205/195405.842537:WARNING:vaapi_wrapper.cc(523)] VAAPI video acceleration not available for disabled` and than idles forever. If I do it with a normal webpage it shows the warning but works.

Other librarys I tried:

```
pdftk form.pdf output page.pdf --> stays as form
convert form.pdf test.pdf --> Only checkboxes are taken, textfields empty
lowriter --convert-to pdf form.pdf --> Error: Please verify input parameters...
pdftops Einsatzprotokoll_2021_02_05.pdf Einsatzprotokoll_2021_02_05.ps\
gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE -dUseCIEColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile=MyOutPutPDF-A.pdf Einsatzprotokoll_2021_02_05.ps --> some fields stay empty
```

Any opinion?

Comment: "...but on in Firefox and Safari some checkboxes and fields are not filled..." start fixing this.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I filled with the PHP-fpdm library ( https://github.com/codeshell/fpdm), so my influence is quite small

Comment: I thought it was a problem in html form, not pdf generated.

Comment: No, the filled PDF-Form is not rendered correctly on all devices. The HTML is fine :)

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/a/1291383

Comment: @notautogenerated partly, but checkboxes are rendered empty :(